# How to verify the given node exists and read the value from azure data factory

Tags: oracle, azure-data-factory, oracle-adf

I have a lookup where I am performing a query to get the `employee_no`

`SELECT employee_no FROM HRS.EMPLOYEE_MASTER WHERE SOC_SEC_NO = '@{variables('FE_SoSecNo')}'` this might return the data as follows

```
{
    "firstRow": {
        "EMPLOYEE_NO": "12345"
    },
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "VMSHIntegrationRuntime",
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "SelfhostedIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ],
        "totalBillableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "SelfhostedIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 3
    }
}
```

Or if there is no data found

```
{
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "VMSHIntegrationRuntime",
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "SelfhostedIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ],
        "totalBillableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "SelfhostedIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 3
    }
}
```

I am adding a step to read the value as follows but when the json node does not exists, what I am trying to to insert if the node value was not present and update by getting the value

`activity('GetEmpBySSN').output.firstRow.employee_no`

[image]
[image]

Can I know how to write the logic to read the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a Boolean variable to check if response of lookup contains `firstrow` node or not and the expression I am using to check the existence of the attribute is this

```
@bool(contains(activity('Lookup1').output, 'firstRow'))
```

**My Boolean variable:**
[image]

**Set variable:**
[image]

**Output:**

- Lookup output doesn't exist firstrow node:
  [image]
- As firstrow node doesn't exist variable is returning false:
  [image]

You can then use that boolean variable in an  [If activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity), to get value of node if it exists conditionally based on the value of the variable.

Comment: `@pratik Lad` thanks can we get the actual value when the json is present?

Comment: yes, after this use if condition based on the result of node existence if true take set variable inter true condition take another set variable to access node value.

Comment: You mean to say like `@equals(variables('emp_exists').value,'true')`

Comment: yes, and under if condition fetch the value of node if exist

Comment: I tired this way is it correct to read the value from `{
 "name": "employee_no",
 "value": 459577
}`  `@json(activity('EmpBySSN').output.firstRow['value'])`

Comment: I tried this way `@int(activity('EmpBySSN').output.firstRow.EMPLOYEE_NO)` but it is giving output as `{
 "name": "employee_no",
 "value": 459577
}` where it should give only 459577

Comment: The JSON on Lookup `EmpBYSSN` is `{
 "firstRow": {
  "EMPLOYEE_NO": "459577"
 },`

Comment: name is variable name it Will come in set variables output. result you are getting is correct.

Comment: OK but I need only the value from this query how can I do that `@int(activity('EmpBySSN').output.firstRow.EMPLOYEE_NO)`

Comment: yes this query will give you only value

Comment: It is giving like this `{"name": "employee_no", "value": 459577 }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256350/discussion-between-developer-and-pratik-lad).

Comment: Got it my bad I need to call it by `@{variables('employee_no')}`